# How is key equivalence defined when using Scala's HashMap?

Tags: scala

When calling the `get` method of Scala's `HashMap` class, which method is used to check if the key exists (i.e. whether a key in the map is *equivalent* to the supplied one)? Is it `==` or another one?

The Scala API does not clearly speak about it:

> "Optionally returns the value associated with a key"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hash maps first check hash value and then check identity.  So the "method" is

```
key.hashCode == entry.hashCode && key == entry
```

(where `key` is the item you're testing and `entry` is an item already in the map).  In particular, `scala.collection.immutable.HashMap` uses exactly this form inside its `get` method (as of Scala version 2.9).

If you want to change the behavior of identity, you therefore need to override `hashCode` and of `equals`, and also you can't rely upon overridden behavior of the item already in the map; it's the one you test with whose equal method gets called.  (But note that in general, no guarantee is made about whose equals method will be called, so you shouldn't rely upon this behavior.)

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the explanation I was looking for (maybe my question was a bit misleading).

Comment: Scala API, Any Class, hashCode:
"Note that it is allowed for two objects to have identical hash codes (o1.hashCode.equals(o2.hashCode)) yet not be equal (o1.equals(o2) returns false). [..] However, it is required that if two objects are equal (o1.equals(o2) returns true) that they have identical hash codes (o1.hashCode.equals(o2.hashCode)). Therefore, when overriding this method, be sure to verify that the behavior is consistent with the equals method. "

With this in mind: Is it right to say, that the hashcode helps to find the element in the HashMap faster, but in the end it depends on == ?

Comment: @JohnThreepwood - No.  It is right to say that HashMap will _not work properly_ unless that condition is true.  In particular, `key.hashCode == entry.hashCode` will return false and the map will never even find that there exists an entry where `key == entry` is true.  (It only looks in spots where the hash codes might be the same--that is the whole point of a hash map.)

Answer (score 0):

> `def contains(key: A): Boolean`
>
> Tests whether this map contains a binding for a key.

and:

> `def get(key: A): Option[B]`
>
> Optionally returns the value associated with a key.

*Optionally* means: either returns a value associated with a given key wrapped in `Some` or `None` if value for such key does not exist.

Comment: You seem to have answered a different question :-)

Comment: @oxbow_lakes: well, I **did** answered the question as it was in its original form (after edit it asks for a completely different thing), so I think downvote wasn't really justified, but nevermind ;-).