# Mutable maps with object keys

Tags: scala, object, dictionary

Why is it that the following will run without exception:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

class Label(val name: String) {
    override def toString = s"Label($name)"
}

object Main extends App {
    var map = mutable.Map[Label, Int]()
    val ab = new Label("AB")
    map += ab -> 1
    println(map(ab))
}
```

Whereas the following will yield a `NoSuchElementException`:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

class Label(val name: String) {
    override def toString = s"Label($name)"
}

object Main extends App {
    var map = mutable.Map[Label, Int]()
    map += new Label("AB") -> 1
    println(map(new Label("AB")))
}
```

I have been unable to find a solution to this, but I believe it must be related to a difference between equality and identity in Scala.

Comment: duplicate of [how-is-key-equivalence-defined-when-using-scalas-hashmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805570/how-is-key-equivalence-defined-when-using-scalas-hashmap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equality and identity in Scala are as in Java. By default, two objects are equal only if they are identical. A class must override `equals` and `hashCode` in order for two distinct objects to be treated as equivalent in hashing data. By default, if those methods are not overridden, any two objects are not "equal" and won't substitute as hash keys.

The main difference between Java and Scala is that the `==` operator tests equality, i.e. uses the `equals` method, while in Java `==` tests identity. (To test identity in Scala, use the `eq` operator.)

So, in your second code snippet, each evaluation of `new Label("AB")` yields a distinct, nonequivaent object. Looking up on the result of the second evaluation cannot resolve to the first.

In Scala  much more than Java, however, the usual practice is to define immutable objects that do override `equals` and `hashCode`. Scala offers the notion of "case classes", which, among other conveniences, override those methods automatically.

You can fix your second code snippet just by putting the word `case` before your class definition for `Label`.

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.mutable

scala> case class Label(val name: String) {
     |     override def toString = s"Label($name)"
     | }
defined class Label

scala> object Main extends App {
     |     var map = mutable.Map[Label, Int]()
     |     map += new Label("AB") -> 1
     |     println(map(new Label("AB")))
     | }
defined object Main

scala> Main.main(Array.empty[String])
1
```

Note that case classes also define a companion object automatically for the class, and an `apply` method that calls the main constructor. So rather than writing `new Label("AB")`, it would be more conventional to simply write `Label("AB")`.